# Calculate $\inf _{a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}} \int_{-1}^{1}\left|x^{3}-a x^{2}-b x-c\right|^{2} d x$

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

> Calculate $$\inf\limits_{a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}} \,\int_{-1}^{1}\left|x^{3}-a x^{2}-b x-c\right|^{2} \mathrm d x$$

I am new to Hilbert space, I see similar questions used the formula: $\langle f, g\rangle=\int f g \, \mathrm d \mu$ (real $L^{2}$), but I am having trouble converting the problem to the formula: What is the systematic way of finding $f$ and  $g$? What role does orthogonality plays in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you want to project $x^{3}$ onto the subspace spanned by $1,x,x^{2}$. Use Gram Schmidt to find an orthonormal basis for this subspace and use the general formula for the projection $Px=\sum   \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i$ for the projection onto the space with orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}$.

Comment: But for the purpose here, the norm is not defined in the question, should we define the norm as the form of this intergral in this case?

Comment: @TheR : The given integral indicates that you are operating in (the real valued) $L^2([-1,1])$ where $||f||^2 = \int_{-1}^1|f(x)|^2\;dx$ and $\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{-1}^1 f(x) g(x) \, dx$.